# How many values of c in the equation $x^2 - 5x + c$ result in rational roots which are integers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

This question was asked in the e-litmus exam.

Comment: Please read about accepting answers [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik No I'm not familiar with that

Comment: it would be better if you can just google "Rational root theorem " and try understanding that... It would not be so difficult...

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $(x-a)(x-b) = x^2 - (a+b) x + ab$.  How many integer solutions does $a+b=5$ have?

Comment: aren't here infinitely many $c,5-c$?

Comment: Yes, good answer.  Unless we restrict $c$ to non-negative integers, there are infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 1):

We have  $$x=\frac{5\pm\sqrt{25-4c}}2$$

So, we need $25-4c$ to be perfect square $=d^2$(say) $\implies c=\frac{25-d^2}4$

If $c\ge0,  25-d^2\ge0\implies d^2\le 25\iff -5\le d\le 5$

If $c$ is integer try with odd(why?) values of $d\in[0,5]$

Answer (score -1):

Answer should be $6$.

In order for $x$ to be an integer, numerator must be even which would be divisible by $2$.
 $d= \sqrt{25-4c}$

$x=(5\pm\sqrt{25-4c}) /2$

Now solve inside the brackets first such that d becomes odd so that the numerator $5\pm$(any odd integer) is divisible by $2$ and and hence $x$ is an integer.

The values of $c$ could be $24/5,-24/5,16/5,-16/5,0$ (though even)